# Android App push notification with AWS (DyanmoDB) and GCM

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I have android app like twitter. I want a push notification on User1 app when User2 follows User1. 
I have AWS (**dynamodb**) as backend and integrated with **GCM**. I am able to publish message from AWS sns console manually also. But i want norification to be sent automatically when someone follows other guy. Right now my app directly talks with DynamoDB there is no server in between.

I want to know to publish notification programatically should i write server where i should make a call to update DynamoDB (instead of directly updating it) and publish message to GCM. OR User1's app itself should publish a message for User2 ?

I need to know very urgently.. I could not find any explanation of that sort anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a backend server and your app only communicates with your server.

Your app requests to your server to send a message to another user, and the server is responsible to update in the DynamoDB and tell SNS to send a push.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a Lot.     Could you please tell me in that case what kind of backend server is best? Does AWS provide any mechanism for that to implement scalable server ?

Comment: "The best" is a little bit subjective. But the trending ones are Ruby on Rails, Play with scala , symphony with php. It really depends of your knowledge of this programming languages